# IntelliJ Community Edition - How to import an Eclipse project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

There seems to be no eclipse support in the IntelliJ Community Edition. Do you know a smart way to import an eclipse project into IntelliJ Community Edition?

See also http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/10/intellij-idea-open-sourced/

Comment: Hello,

I can't import a intellij IDEA Project into the Eclipse. Please help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see the [IntelliJ IDEA Editions Comparison](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/editions_comparison_matrix.html). Eclipse project interoperability is listed as available for both editions. It's not available in the first preview release because of the bug in our build subsystem. The updated build with Eclipse import support will be published later today. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

Use Maven, stop relying on IDEs.

Comment: Wow, just wow. Do you have any idea how steep maven learning curve is?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the paid edition without any problem.  You'll see the option to do so when you first open IntelliJ.  If it's not there, perhaps they left it out of the community edition.

Comment: I just installed 9.0.1 community edition and tried it, it's there (do "create new project", then it gives you the option of importing from an eclipse model)