# How to open project written on Eclipse with IntelliJ?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I have one Eclipse project and I want to open it in IntelliJ, so what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ Community Edition - How to import an Eclipse project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577138/intellij-community-edition-how-to-import-an-eclipse-project)

Answer (score -1):

"File->New->Project from existing sources..."

Very simple to import projects from other IDE's into Idea

Comment: Imported project refers to unknown jdks JavaSE-1.8 ? What does that mean ?

Comment: Click on "Project Structure" (top right corner "Two Files and Stairs Icon
) then click on "Project" then click "New..." and select JDK and point it to the correct location of your JDK. Also make sure to set your "Project Language Level" to the appropriate one.

Answer (score -2):

refer to [Import Eclipse Workspace](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/import-eclipse-workspace.html)